# Is XML and SOAP over TCP stateful in a WebService?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

TCP is a stateful protocol and it can maintain state between client and server interaction. SOAP maintain communication neutrality and can be used over any transport protocol such as HTTP, SMTP, TCP, or JMS, so if we are using SOAP as protocol for data exchange and it is maintained over TCP protocol than whether WebService will maintain its state while doing interaction with client.

Comment: I changed your Topic to actually be a QUESTION. I suggest you get rid of your cultural programming and make question questions that end in a ?. I Know some cultures do not like that.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I will take care of it in future

Comment: Great. Makes things a lot easier. You really Need to come "hard". The more specific, the clearer, the better to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the service. With WCF, it is possible to create both stateful and stateless services when using TCP. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040.aspx and ServiceContractAttribute.SessionMode for more info.

Comment: Hi Eugene but can we make stateful webservice while using tcp as communication protocol

Comment: As he said, yes you can. IT is dangerous, though - i have Long gone towards maintaining state with Logical session Cookies so I CAN reconnect. But if you read the documetnation linked, you see it is possible to make stateful OR stateless, as YOU want.

Comment: But this document is about WCF and I like to know is it possible in webservice ?

Comment: By "webservice" I assume you mean ASP.NET Web Services ("asmx"), the technology that preceded WCF? I believe this is possible with Web Service Enhancements (WSE 3.0, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms977317.aspx ) - I've never used it myself, but supposedly it adds both TCP support and support for stateful sessions. Though, again, unfortunately I don't know much about the technology.